# Modelica getTime not available

Tags: dependencies, modelica, localtime, gettime

I am unable to access the Modelica.Utilities.System.getTime() function on Modelica. For some reason it does not exist in the MSL in Plug-in dependencies. Any idea how to import this? 
[image]

Comment: Which tool are you using?

Comment: Looks like OneModelica, which also is listed at https://modelica.org/tools, but no longer publically available.

Comment: I am using dymola as the GUI and compiler. Although I can find the getTime function in MSL in Dymola, I am unable to find it in my project explorer in One Modelica.

Answer (score 3):

[Modelica.Utilities.System.getTime](https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%203.2.3/Resources/helpOM/Modelica.Utilities.System.getTime.html) was added for MSL 3.2.2 (April 2016). Is it possible that you loaded an older version of the MSL?

Comment: I can see the getTime() function in dymola MSL but not in One Modelica when I'm working on my project. Hence when I use the Modelica.Utilities.System.getTime, Modelica gives me an error saying it cannot find the function getTime. As shown in the picture the MSL imported under Plug-in dependencies does not show getTime function listed. Any idea how to update it or import it ?

Comment: Is there any other way to get the local time in Modelica if I cannot use Modelica.Utilities.System.getTime()?

Comment: You can just download the newer MSL, and either use that, or copy the relevant functions to your library.

Comment: That will not work out of the box, since ModelicaInternal_gettime of ModelicaInternal.[ch] requires an updated ModelicaExternalC to be provided by the tool vendor.